# Win32API: определить тип кодировки

Tags: c, winapi

Есть текстовый файл, необходимо опредлить тип кодировки: однобайтовая или двухбайтовая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл в двухбайтной кодировке он может содержать символ BOM, символ этот хранится в начале текста и он непечатаемый. Для кодировки Windows 1251 это такой символ "п»ї" также есть шестнадцатиричный эквивалент. Соответственно в однобайтной кодировке такого нет.Проблема ,правда, несколько шире т.к есть UTF-8 без бом,но в рамки моей задачи это входит. Тут приведена более подробная информация о BOM https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

Вам скорее всего поможет `IsTextUnicode`.
Она может определить и 2-хбайтовые кодировки, и найдет BOM (при наличии), и даже `ENDIAN` определит. Конечно, все это не гарантирует 100% результат, это уже зависит от объема исходного текста.